# How to change the position of date picker in textbox in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to change the position of date picker in text box using JQuery

```
<input type="text" id="Date" name="Date" class='Date'/>
```

Jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 (function ($) {
        $('.Date').datepicker();
        $('.Date').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here how to change the position of date picker down to left side and How to Decrease the height and width in this

Comment: Take a look at the CSS, that's how you customize jQuery UI widgets.

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669502/changing-the-height-of-a-jquery-datepicker

Comment: some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1346680/584505

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

```
  $('.Date').datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst)
        {
            inst.dpDiv.css({marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px'});
        }
    });
```